# Modifying Postgres SQL queries with rules

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view, rules

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to write rules for Postgres to dynamically alter queries at runtime.

Essentially, I have a multitenancy solution that uses a mapping table to determine if a row is owned by a tenant. I've simplified the examples below for easy reading.

In these examples, "car" table is scoped to a particular tenant by a `carmapping` table which has foreign keys `scoped_model_id` pointing at the `car` table and `scoping_model_pk` pointing at the tenant/customer/whatever model that can generically be considered a "scoping model" used to scope various tables in the application.

Example scoped query:

```
SELECT "car"."id" FROM "car" WHERE 
("car"."id" IN (SELECT U0."scoped_model_id" FROM "carmapping" U0 WHERE U0."scoping_model_pk" IN (1));
```

Original query:

```
SELECT "car"."id" FROM "car";
```

Is there a way to use rules to dynamically add these WHERE clauses? 
It would need to be capable of determining what `scoping_model_pk` is active in the current request - whether that is passed to Postgres as an additional piece of metadata for all db cursor connections or embedded as a noop string somehow within the SQL statement itself. And will also need to determine what the mapping table is for the model currently targeted by the SELECT statement - in this case, `carmapping`.

We can do this easily at the application level within the ORM, but it would be best to do at the db level for consistency (because we have some code not using the ORM and don't want to have to remember to update any raw SQL code).

Comment: Would it be an acceptable option to use a pl/pgsql function?  If so then you could use dynamic sql to do this.

Comment: Not sure, thanks for the input though I will look into pl/pgsql